# How to read two blocks of multiple lines separated by a newline from std input in java

Tags: java

How do I read each of these block of lines and write them  into two different objects in java. I was using Scanner for the first block of lines. I have not attempted the second block

```
6 6

3 5 5 3

4 6 6 4

2 8 2

6 6

Busayo 2
Ojo 5
Ajala 6
Gulliver 100
Antonio 3
Trump 4
```

This is what I came up with

```
public class mainControl {

private Position position;  

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Write the functionalities to read data in 

    int row = 1;    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    sc.useDelimiter("\n");

    while (sc.hasNext()) {      

        String value = sc.next();           
        Position pos = new Position(value);
        //System.out.println();
        System.out.println(pos);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 row: 6 6

 row: 

 row: 3 5 5 3

 row: 

 row: 4 6 6 4

 row: 

 row: 2 8  2

 row:
```

how do I also remove the extra newline that the scanner reads from std in?

Thanks.

Comment: Add condition before your `println` call like `if (!value.equals(""))`

Comment: Your program will also read the second block ...

Comment: Which is the first block of lines and which is the second? Alternatively, what are all those blocks after the first two? What is the principle here?

Comment: Check if the line equals \n

Comment: @EJP the block with numbers is the first block while the second one is with names. I want to be able to read them into different objects without reading the white spaces and the newline.

Comment: @Hiren Pandit  I tried that but nothing changes.

Comment: @Zoe  I tried that but nothing changes.

Comment: And what is the principle that says the first block can have blank lines but the second one can't, and the principle that says where the first block ends?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone I figured out the spaces between the block of numbers are not necessary so I removed them and  found a way around reading the two blocks separately.  I am thinking there are better ways to do this though, but this is what I have got for now.

```
public class mainControl {  
private static  List<Position> layoutArray = new ArrayList<Position>();
private static List<Order> orderArray = new ArrayList<Order>();
private static Layout layout = new Layout();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {     
    // TODO Write the functionalities to read data in       

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int row = 1;

    while(sc.hasNextInt()) {

        String[] line = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
        for (int i =0; i < line.length; i++) {

            Position pos = new Position(row, i+1, Integer.parseInt(line[i]));
            layoutArray.add(pos);
            layout.addCapacity(Integer.parseInt(line[i]));      
            //System.out.println(pos);
        }   
        row++;
    }

    System.out.println();   

    while(sc.hasNextLine()) {       

            String[] str = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
            if(str.length > 1) {

                Order order = new Order(str[0], Integer.parseInt(str[1]));
                orderArray.add(order);
                //System.out.println(order);    
            }       
    }

    sc.close();
```